# How to stop a Bitbucket Pipeline from building?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting, bitbucket-pipelines

Is there any way we can stop a Bitbucket Pipeline from building?

The process is taking more than 25 minutes?

.yml file content is :-

```
image: node:8.9.4
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - if [ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH == 'master' ]; then
          - npm install -g @angular/cli
          - npm install -g firebase-tools
          - npm install
          - ng build
          - firebase deploy --only hosting --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN" --public dist
          - fi
```

Comment: Did you find solution? If yes, pls, post it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

What about that button on the right:
[image]
?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Actually, i disabled the pipeline first and then was trying to stop it.So it was not working.Figured it out after half an hour. :-)

Comment: stop button is disabled and build seems to be freezed. How can I force stop?

Answer (score 2):

You are installing all the libraries from npm on each run, use a docker image which has npm and firebase tools already installed like this one: https://hub.docker.com/r/devillex/docker-firebase/ , this will bring down the build time significantly

Answer (score 2):

You may set max-time for bitbucket pipeline:

```
options:
  max-time: 15
pipelines:
  branches:
     .........
```

By adding the above property, your bitbucket pipeline will automatically abort after 15 minutes.

Comment: Additionally you can also mention it locally for a particular step to fail after a certian number of minutes. Check the `max-time` section in this Atlassian support document.
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/#Configurebitbucket-pipelines.yml-ci_max-time

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you already found the answer but note that you can also include `[skip ci]` in your commit message when you push to your repository. Unless this updates an existing pull-request linked to a build, it should not trigger your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean stopped working.
try it.

project_name -> setting -> pipeline setting -> setting -> Enable Pipelines